# Plot values per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have some dataframe like this

| param 1 | param b | date 1 | date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accepted | Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |
| nor Accepted | Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |
| Accepted | Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |
| not Accepted | not Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |
| Accepted | Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |
| Accepted | Accepted | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 | 2023-06-26 09:59:09 |

I should plot graphs with curve for each param.

1. Calculate values in column 1 (how many have "accepted") and plot dependences from date 1
2. Calculate values in column 2 (how many have "accepted") and plot dependences from date 2

How i can do it? I want use it in jupyter with interactive selector, where I can choose param from drop down list.

```
y=len(df_v[(df_v['param1']=='accepted')])
df.plot(x=df.["data1"], y=y)
plt.xlabel("Date",  size = 20)
plt.ylabel("Values", size = 20)
plt.title("Dependences", size = 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) is one of the packages you can use to handle this, but it's not the only one. You'll easily find trainings online.
As an example, I created this code for you to test it. I didn't really understand what you want to achieve, so I assumed the parameter you wanted is a selection of `['Accepted' - 'Not accepted']`.

You can test the below in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, RadioButtonGroup, ColumnDataSource, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import random
import math
from faker import Faker  # used here to generate random dates

fake = Faker()
output_notebook()
```

```
def create_plots(doc):
    
    # create fake dataframe
    options = ['Accepted', 'Not accepted']
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'param': [random.choice(options) for _ in range(20)],
        'date': [fake.date_between(start_date='-5d', end_date='today') for _ in range(20)]
    })
    df_grouped = df[df['param'] == options[0]][['date', 'param']].groupby(by=['date']).count()

    # create source and figure
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df_grouped)
    p = figure(title="Param 1", x_axis_type='datetime', tools = [BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool()])
    p.line(x='date', y='param', source=source)
    
    # optional - formatting x axis
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.radians(45)
    p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
        hours=["%d %B %Y"],
        days=["%d %B %Y"],
    )
    p.xaxis.ticker.desired_num_ticks = 5
        
    # create widget
    radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=options, active=0)
    
    # update the chart after a click on an event
    radio_button_group.js_on_click(CustomJS(code="""
        console.log('radio_button_group: active=' + this.active, this.toString())
    """))
        
    def update_data(status):
        df_grouped = df[df['param'] == status][['date', 'param']].groupby(by=['date']).count()
        source.data = df_grouped
        
    def update(attr, old, new):
        status = options[radio_button_group.active]
        update_data(status)

    radio_button_group.on_change('active', update)
    
    # layout
    doc.add_root(column(radio_button_group, p))

show(create_plots)
```